# FireFox & flash extensions i have problem with externalInterface (

Tags: flash, firefox, windows-7, externalinterface

how i can communicate with my flash app ? i load in my extension flash 
some like this

```
myDiv.innerHTML = <object…><param allowScriptAsses… etc … 
flash load fine !!! now, i trace my externalInterface method 
var flashObject = document.get…("myFlash")
alert(flashObject) <- okey - [embedHtmlObject … 
alert(flashObject.myExternalMethod) <- native function its okey !!! 
try excute 
flashObject.myExternalMethod() and NOTHING !!! ((( externalMEthod not invoked !!! this problem ONLY on windows 7 in fireFox !
```

on mac os and firefox i use wrapedObject and externalInterface work fine ! but if i try use wrapedObject on windows system - i have error (((

HOW i can use ExternalInterface on windows in firefox  correctly ?

Comment: First don't use innerHTML to embed flash. Second use SWFObject. Third make sure the flash app is loaded fully before you access callback methods inside the swf.

Comment: i can't use SWFObject ( is unreal - i inject my flashObject on current open page in open browser or open tab - SWFObject can inject only current document ! my current document != document in opened browser) my flash app loaded full ! i sure ! any body hove any ideas ?

Comment: Now you just confused the hell out of me. You are using javascript to talk between browser tabs/documents? SWFObject i9s a method to embed flash if you have your target container "myDiv" then you can use SWFObject to embed it

Comment: i now BUT SWFObject embed on CURRENT DOCUMENT ! SWFOBJECT search container "myDiv" in CURRENT document ! my flash embed NOT currentDocument ! i develop extension for FF and my extension embed flash object in open web page ! swfObject work in my extension and document IN my extension != document in opened webPage

Comment: ah i see now. I bet this is an issue with you trying to access the swf before it is initialized and done loading. try pausing a few seconds before you try to access it.

Comment: i sure, my swf file loaded 100%, anyway i fix my problem ))) i inject my jsCode in div and div inject on some document, next i write code in injectedJS for connect to my page, after connect i can execute all method in injected code from my root code ! injected code very fine work with externalInterface in div )))

Comment: Can you, please, explain how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a callback to your ActionScript code:

```
flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("myExternalMethod", doSomething);

function doSomething():void
{
//your code
}
```

If you are using swfObject to embed your flash movie you can use *swfobject.getObjectById* to detect your swf and call your methods.

```
swfobject.getObjectById("myFlash").myExternalMethod();
```

If you are not using swfObject just copy and past the getObjectById method on your JS code:

```
function getObjectById(objectIdStr) {
        var r = null;
        var o = getElementById(objectIdStr);
        if (o && o.nodeName == "OBJECT") {
            if (typeof o.SetVariable != UNDEF) {
                r = o;
            }
            else {
                var n = o.getElementsByTagName(OBJECT)[0];
                if (n) {
                    r = n;
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

And call it by doing:

```
getObjectById("myFlash").myExternalMethod();
```

**Have a look on this, I actually code a small example on my blog:** http://www.nelsond8.com/?p=515